# How to deploy .gitignored compiled files in Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, github, version-control, web-deployment

I have a compiled folder named `/target` where my `server.js` lives. Since it's compiled files, I added `/target` to `.gitignore` since I don't want all those changes checked it into my GitHub.

But Heroku ignores anything listed in the `.gitignore`, so I'm unable to spin up the app.

Ideally I'd like to run `node /target/scripts/server.js` in Heroku. And not have the compiled `/target` folder checked into GitHub.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Maybe have a separate branch where `/target` is checked in, and push it only to heroku?

Comment: Generally you should let Heroku generate the built files itself. How are you generating the files in `target/`?

Comment: `/target` is generated by `./lein cljsbuild auto dev`. Since the compilation takes longer than 60 seconds, Heroku stops the deploy process: `heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)`
`heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Comment: `/target` is small. All the compiled files are about 8MB total.

Comment: When are you running `./lein cljsbuild auto dev`?

Comment: @mipadi currently before I deploy to Heroku. If I run that on Heroku, I get the 60 seconds limit.

Comment: @HenryZhu i hope you somewhat resolved the issue, anyway added my answer for someone that come across this question !

Answer (score 6):

Seems like none answered this question, hope this will help someone :)

**Step 1**: create a seperate branch for heroku that contains your target folder, say `myheroku`.

```
git checkout -b myheroku
```

**Step 2**: modify `.gitignore` by removing `target/`, run your command `lein cljsbuild` to generate production files.

```
git add target/  
git commit -m "your commit message"
```

**Step3**: push the branch with target changes to heroku

```
git push heroku myheroku:master
```

So, after working & finished testing,

- checkout your `heroku` local branch; can generate build files
- commit & push from localbranch to heroku master as **Step3**

NOTE: i hope there is no problem for you dealing with that `extra` commit messages polluting heroku localbranch.

Comment: Actually, it might be better to append to `.gitignore` using negation pattern, rather than directly editing it.